# Kentico 9: Timeout error when importing a large list of email subscribers

Tags: kentico

In Kentico 9, when importing a large list (>2000) of email marketing subscribers via Kentico's built in import function (email marketing > subscriber management > Import subscribers), I often encounter a timeout error:

> Exception occurred: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The executionTimeout is set to 2400 under "httpRuntime executionTimeout" in the web.config.  This seems like plenty, and much longer than it takes to hit that timeout error.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Split your list up into sets of 500 or 1000 instead.  This is the easy fix.

Also, I don't believe the issue for the timeout is pertaining to the `executionTimeout` setting in the web.config.  You'd need to update the timeout in the connection string.  If I remember right the import process does a select statement against the `Newsletter_Subscriber` table for every subscriber imported (not very efficient).  So change the connection string timeout.